# ScrollView for whole interface

Tags: android, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have implemented an interface with two scrollviews - HorizontalScrollView for some imageViews and a vertical scrollView with few textViews. Now i want a vertical scrollView for whole interface. How can i do this? Please help me. Here is .xml file for the interface :-

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rahulshaw.myfragmentsexample.HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textStyle = "bold|italic"
    android:queryHint="@string/search"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hospital" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cities"
    android:id="@+id/cities"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/Container">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:text="@string/bengaluru"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/bengaluru"
    android:background="@drawable/bengaluru"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:text="@string/chennai"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/chennai"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="@drawable/chennai"
    android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="@string/kolkata"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/kolkata"
        android:background="@drawable/kolkata"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="@string/mumbai"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mumbai"
        android:background="@drawable/mumbai"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ScrolView as Parent which helps scrolling vertically and inside that first element will be your Horizontal Scroll View which will make your View scroll Horizontal

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             //your Contents here

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended. Actually, it's recommended not to do this, and not supported out of the box. What you could do is something like the following:

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});

childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

But it's really not recommended. Things can get fiddly very quickly if you try this anyways. Imagine the inner scrollview taking up all of the screen on small devices, good luck scrolling the outer one then.